# Context when adding new items in Catel MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, catel

In Catel.MVVM:
In the case when **adding** a new `Customer` where a property `Id1` is still null, the `IdDocumentView` would have an `IdDocumentViewModel` context when there is a match on a constructor (one that does not have an `IdDocument` parameter) leading to a `ViewModel` with no `Model`. Is there a standard way of working with this scenario, maybe by setting `customer.Id1` to an instance of `IdDocument` with default values so that the `View` has a context allowing for binding to update the values of the `IdDocument` instance?

Structure:

`MainView : Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl`

_|--`CustomerWindow : Catel.Windows.Window`

___|--`IdDocumentView : Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl`

Model Classes:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    [DomainSignature]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Lookup PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Lookup Occupation { get; set; }

    public IdDocument Id1 { get; set; }

    public IdDocument Id2 { get; set; }

}

public class IdDocument : Entity
{
    [DomainSignature]
    public Lookup IdType { get; set; }

    [DomainSignature]
    public string IdCode { get; set; }

    [DomainSignature]
    public DateTime IdExpiry { get; set; }
}
```

In `CustomerView`

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <GroupBox Header="ID 1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0">
        <local:IdDocumentView DataContext="{Binding Id1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </GroupBox>
</DockPanel>
<orccontrols:EmptyColumn />
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <GroupBox Header="ID 2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0">
        <local:IdDocumentView DataContext="{Binding Id2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </GroupBox>
</DockPanel>
```

`IdDocumentView`

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="CTT.MTS.Views.IdDocumentView"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CTT.MTS.Views"
                   xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
                   xmlns:orccontrols="http://schemas.wildgums.com/orc/controls"
                   xmlns:app="clr-namespace:CTT.MTS.Model"
                   xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CTT.MTS.Controls"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <orccontrols:StackGrid>

        <!-- Row definitions -->
        <orccontrols:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </orccontrols:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Column definitions -->
        <orccontrols:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </orccontrols:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Type" />
        <ComboBox ShouldPreserveUserEnteredPrefix="False" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding IdTypes}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding IdTypeText}" Width="100"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Code" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding IdCode}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <Label Content="Expiry" />
        <orccontrols:DatePicker Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Height="40"
            Value="{Binding IdExpiry, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
        </orccontrols:DatePicker>
    </orccontrols:StackGrid>
</catel:UserControl>
```

in `MainViewModel` in a command method for a `Button` click

```
 await uiVisualizerService.ShowAsync<CustomerViewModel>(new Customer
{
    DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1981, 8, 8),
    Gender = Gender.Male,
    FirstName = "Muhammad",
    Id1 = new IdDocument { IdType = idType, IdCode = "1111", IdExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) },
    //Id2 = new IdDocument(),
    Addresses = new List<CustomerAddress>(new[]
        {new CustomerAddress {Address = address, AddressType = addressType, IsCurrent = true}})
});
```

notice `Id2`'s initialization is commented. If left like that *null* `IdDocumentView` would have no link to an `IdDocument` model

`IdDocumentViewModel`'s constructors

```
public IdDocumentViewModel(ILookupService lookupService)
{

    Argument.IsNotNull(() => lookupService);
    this.lookupService = lookupService;

    IdTypes = lookupService.IdTypes;

}

public IdDocumentViewModel(IdDocument idDocument, ILookupService lookupService) :this(lookupService)
{

    IdDocument = idDocument;
    IdTypeText = idDocument.IdType?.Value ?? "";
}
```

Note that I added the first *less arguments* constructor after noticing the constructor with an `IdDocument` parameter not being called for `Customer.Id1` when it is null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You assumption is correct that:

1. Catel will first try to construct a vm with model injection
2. If that's not possible, it will use the one with the most parameters it can construct
3. If that's not possible, no VM will be constructed

In such cases, I normally pass in a temporary (new) model without an id. This way, the "child vm" knows it's in create state instead of edit.